# Javascript http request problem

Tags: javascript, httpwebrequest

I want to get an automatic search result, and on one page it DOES work but on the other NOT. Could you tell me what te problem is?

WORKING:

```
function showUser(str)
{

if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
{
document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
}
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","ordertabel.php?search="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

NOT WORKING:

```
function showUser(str,str)
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
{
document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
}
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","klanttabel.php?search="+str"&search2="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send(); 
}
```

Please note that with the NOT working code there are 2 inputs.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try the url from the location bar in a browser or use firebug to see the http traffic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it's an url encoding problem. Try encoding:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET", "klanttabel.php?search=" + encodeURIComponent(str) + "&search2=" + encodeURIComponent(str), true);
```

Also notice that you are missing a `+` in your string concatenation.

Comment: Hmm it does 'search' automatically now, but it doesn't return any results. Any thing I could try?

Answer (score 1):

Probably because you use two variables in your function method with the same name and you are missing a PLUS sign in your xmlhttp.open() method...

Try:

```
function showUser(str, str2) {
   ...code...
   xmlhttp.open("GET", "klanttabel.php?search="+str+"&search2="+str2, true);
   xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Another suggestion, making Ajax calls is way easier when using JQuery.

```
$.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: "klanttabel.php",
   data: ({search : str,
           search2 : str2}),
   success: function(data) {
     $('#txtHint').html(data);
   }
});
```

Comment: I don't know anything about ajax but I guess just copying the code doesn't work? Actually, I tried it but it doesn't work. Is there anything I need to add to make the ajax work?

Comment: Yes, you should include the standard JQuery library in your project as the following:  `<script src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.5/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>`  Then it'll work and the code is way shorter and easier to maintain or adapt than your current.

Answer (score 0):

Your parameters are named the same... change them.

```
function showUser(strA,strB)
```

and change them later in the function:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","klanttabel.php?search=" + strA + "&search2=" + strB,true);
```

You also had an error where a `+` was missing.

Comment: No i still don't get automatic search, and if i get one from one of the answers above it searches not combined like it does when you click on search..

Comment: @AndreWoons in that case I'm not sure you've posted enough code... can we see the HTML where the output results go, and the button/event that calls this search function?

Comment: If I hit enter it does work like it is supposed to but just that automatic search does not work. One of the other answers suggested using Jquery but how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing plus sign

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","klanttabel.php?search="+str"&search2="+str,true);
```

plus sign after first str

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","klanttabel.php?search="+str+"&search2="+str,true);
```